# Pandas: Having trouble correctly merging data

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Let's say I have data similar to the following:
df:

| Student | Week 1 Grade |
| --- | --- |
| John | 93 |
| Sally | 72 |
| James | 93 |
| Jim | 72 |

df1:

| Student | Week 2 Grade |
| --- | --- |
| John | 87 |
| James | 93 |
| Jim | 72 |

I want to merge these two, and I figure I should use an outer join, but this is what I'm getting:

| Student | Week 1 Grade | Student | Week 2 Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 93 | John | 87 |
| Sally | 72 | James | 93 |
| James | 93 | Jim | 72 |
| Jim | 72 | NaN | NaN |

This is what I'd like to get:

| Student | Week 1 Grade | Week 2 Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 93 | 87 |
| Sally | 72 | NaN |
| James | 93 | 93 |
| Jim | 72 | 72 |

The ordering of *Student* varies in each DataFrame, and there are some names in df that are not present in df1.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I use how='left', it is dropping rows that are present in one dataframe that are not present in another.

Comment: `df.merge(df1, on='Student', how='outer')` works for this example as well.

Comment: `df.merge(df1, on='Student', how='outer')` ended up working. I thought I had tried that but apparently I did not. Thank you!